# appropriate sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am a little unsure of my answer to the question below. Please help:

Suppose you are given a list of N integers. All but one of the integers are sorted in numerical order. Identify a sorting algorithm which will sort this special case in O(N) time and  explain why this sorting algorithm achieves O(N) runtime in this case.

I think it is insertion sort but am not sure why that is the case.

Thanks!!

Comment: What is your answer to the question and why are you unsure?

Comment: This sounds like a homework/quiz/exam question that is checking to see if you've done the requisite work to learn the characteristics of the various sorting algorithms... You won't learn much if someone just gives you the answer...

Comment: Looking at it now, I realize that I did not word the question properly . I had chosen insertion sort as well but did not know how to justify it which is why I posted the entire question so that there was no confusion. I will keep in mind what you said for the future. Thank you for pointing it out....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insertion sort is adaptive, and is efficient for substantially sorted data set. It can sort almost sorted data in O(n+d) where d is number of inversions and in your case d is 1.